# Exporting MapSeries using index layer NAME, instead of page number, in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, map-series

How can I write this python script to export each page in a MapSeries to a PDF, whilst using the MapSeries index layer NAME as the file name? At the moment, the script is configured to export using the page number.

Is it as simple as replacing 'ms.currentPageNumber' and 'pageNum' with 'ms.currentPageName' and 'pageNam'? And would the {0} need removing on the final line?

```
import arcpy, os, sys
relpath = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])

p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("C:\\Automation\\Automation.aprx")
print ("project located")
l = p.listLayouts()[0]
print ("layouts listed")
if not l.mapSeries is None:
  ms = l.mapSeries
  if ms.enabled:
    for pageNum in range(1, ms.pageCount + 1):
      ms.currentPageNumber = pageNum
      print("Exporting page {0} of {1}".format(str(ms.currentPageNumber), str(ms.pageCount)))
      l.exportToPDF("C:\\Users\\Default\\Production\\Completed_certificates\\Exported_PDF_file_{0}".format(str(ms.currentPageNumber) + ".pdf"))
```

Comment: If there is not something more direct you could always use list comprehension with a search cursor on the index layer to write a dictionary with objectid and page name as its key value pairs.  Then use the dictionary to switch page number (objectid) for page name.

Comment: @PolyGeo The index layer is updated every day, with new features replacing those from the previous day. If I understand what you're suggesting, I could not write a dictionary of all map index features, as I don't know what they will be called each day.

Comment: The dictionary would be written as part of this script using one line of code that takes a second or two to run.  I don't think it being volatile will be an issue.

Comment: @PolyGeo ok fair. But I'll have to research how to do that.
However, is there definitely no such thing as ms.currentPageName?

Comment: The documentation should tell you that. I have not had chance to look.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this? I can't even get the page number to export properly. Kind of disappointed that my ArcMap script doesn't work any more, and there doesn't seem to be much example code posted.

Comment: @Carolyn no not yet :( I can only export to page name if doing it from within ArcGIS Pro itself, not via an external script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value of any field in the dataset which is used to generate the map series by using the `ms.pageRow.FIELD_NAME`

Try this:

```
l.exportToPDF("C:\\Path_to_Output\\Exported_PDF_file_{0}".format(str(ms.pageRow.NAME_FIELD) + ".pdf", 300))
```

Comment: thanks. Sorted it with: 
l.exportToPDF(r"D:\\path\\SitePlan-SP-_{0}".format(ms.pageRow.NAME_FIELD) + ".pdf")